# How to register Spring Cloud config server before any XML bean is declared?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to migrate a spring app who uses PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to resolve all the XML placeholders in it's bean declarations to a spring cloud usage, I can check that the config server is contacted and responds with the respective data generated from a git repository, however, at server startup during the BeanFactoryPostProcessor registration the XML context fails to resolve the placeholders.

I assumed that by removing the bean definition:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    <property name="properties">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter"
            factory-method="getProperties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <ref bean="domainConfiguration" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And adding the POM dependency for config client and respective enviroment variables the placeholders should work but they dont.

Can I manually set the config server in a higher priority?

Or as an alternative, teach PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to consume a config server?

Comment: As an alternative (teach PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to consume a config server), you can make usage of the interface EnvironmentAware, and implement setters and getters for an Environment variable wich will be injected (without using @Autowired), and override the methods to resolve said placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spring-cloud-config, this should work out of the box. When spring will build/start the `ApplicationContext`, first it will create a bootstrap (parent) context which will happen before creating the main context. Getting the properties of the config server should happen in the bootstrap phase so that your beans which are created in the normal context should be able to get those properties.

Check out the Client Side Usage part of the documentation for an example and check out the usage of the `bootstrap.properties` file.

If you don't have spring-boot (it should work w/o it as well but the docs are spring-boot centric), check out [this repo](https://github.com/marcellodesales/spring-mvc-with-spring-cloud-config-client-without-springboot) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/299), you will need a `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator`.

Comment: Indeed this project does not use spring-boot, I suspect this is the result of the interference of PPC with spring-cloud-config.